# Spark date format issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, date-format

I have observed weird behavior in spark date formatting. Actually I need to convert the date `yy` to `yyyy`. After date conversion it should be 20yy in date

I have tried as below, it failing after 2040 year.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df=   Seq(("06/03/35"),("07/24/40"), ("11/15/43"), ("12/15/12"), ("11/15/20"), ("12/12/22")).toDF("Date")

df.withColumn("newdate", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp($"Date", "mm/dd/yy"), "mm/dd/yyyy")).show

+--------+----------+
|    Date|   newdate|
+--------+----------+
| 06/3/35|06/03/2035|
|07/24/40|07/24/2040|
|11/15/43|11/15/1943|  // Here year appended with 19
|12/15/12|12/15/2012|
|11/15/20|11/15/2020|
|12/12/22|12/12/2022|
+--------+----------+
```

Why this behavior, Is there any date utility function that I can use directly without appending 20 to string date

Comment: Using spark 2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing 2-digit year strings is subject to some relative interpretation that is documented in the [`SimpleDateFormat` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> For parsing with the abbreviated year pattern ("y" or "yy"), SimpleDateFormat must interpret the abbreviated year relative to some century. It does this by adjusting dates to be within 80 years before and 20 years after the time the SimpleDateFormat instance is created. For example, using a pattern of "MM/dd/yy" and a SimpleDateFormat instance created on Jan 1, 1997, the string "01/11/12" would be interpreted as Jan 11, 2012 while the string "05/04/64" would be interpreted as May 4, 1964.

So, `2043` being more than 20 years away, the parser uses 1943 as documented.

Here's one approach that uses a UDF that explicitly calls `set2DigitYearStart` on a `SimpleDateFormat` object before parsing the date (I picked 1980 just as an example):

```
def parseDate(date: String, pattern: String): Date = {

    val format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1980)
    val beginning = cal.getTime();

    format.set2DigitYearStart(beginning)

    return new Date(format.parse(date).getTime);
}
```

And then:

```
val custom_to_date = udf(parseDate _);
df.withColumn("newdate", custom_to_date($"Date", lit("mm/dd/yy"))).show(false)
```

```
+--------+----------+
|Date    |newdate   |
+--------+----------+
|06/03/35|2035-01-03|
|07/24/40|2040-01-24|
|11/15/43|2043-01-15|
|12/15/12|2012-01-15|
|11/15/20|2020-01-15|
|12/12/22|2022-01-12|
+--------+----------+
```

Knowing your data, you would know which value to pick for the parameter to `set2DigitYearStart()`