# Spark : Parse a Date / Timestamps with different Formats (MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm, MM/dd/yy H:mm ) in same column of a Dataframe

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark, datetime, apache-spark-sql

The problem is: I have a dataset where a column having 2 or more types of date format.
In general I select all values as String type and then use the `to_date` to parse the date.
But I don't know how do I parse a column having two or more types of date formats.

```
val DF= Seq(("02-04-2020 08:02"),("03-04-2020 10:02"),("04-04-2020 09:00"),("04/13/19 9:12"),("04/14/19 2:13"),("04/15/19 10:14"), ("04/16/19 5:15")).toDF("DOB")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{to_date, to_timestamp}
val DOBDF = DF.withColumn("Date", to_date($"DOB", "MM/dd/yyyy"))
```

Output from the above command:

```
null
null
null
0019-04-13
0019-04-14
0019-04-15
0019-04-16
```

The code above I have written is not working for the format `MM/dd/yyyy` and the format which did not provided for that I am getting the `null` as a output.

So seeking the help to parse the file with different date formats.
If possible kindly also share some tutorial or notes to the deal with the date formats.
Please note: I am using Scala for the spark framework.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: values are not consistent with the given date pattern. Make a regex, filter by that and then parse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check **EDIT** section to use Column functions instead of UDF for performance benefits  in later part of this solution --

Well, Let's do it try-catch way.. Try a column conversion against each format and keep the success value.
You may have to provide all possible format from outside as parameter or keep a master list of all possible formats somewhere in code itself..

Here is the possible solution.. ( Instead of SimpleDateFormatter which sometimes have issues on timestamps beyond milliseconds, I use new library - java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter)

Create a to_timestamp Function, which accepts string to convert to timestamp and all possible Formats

```
  import java.time.LocalDate
  import java.time.LocalDateTime
  import java.time.LocalTime
  import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
  import scala.util.Try

def toTimestamp(date: String, tsformats: Seq[String]): Option[java.sql.Timestamp] = {

    val out = (for (tsft <- tsformats) yield {
      val formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .appendPattern(tsft).toFormatter()
      if (Try(java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter))).isSuccess)
        Option(java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter)))
      else None

    }).filter(_.isDefined)
    if (out.isEmpty) None else out.head
  }
```

Create a UDF on top of it - ( this udf takes Seq of Format strings as parameter)

```
 def UtoTimestamp(tsformats: Seq[String]) = org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf((date: String) => toTimestamp(date, tsformats))
```

And now, simply use it in your spark code.. Here's the test with your Data -

```
    val DF = Seq(("02-04-2020 08:02"), ("03-04-2020 10:02"), ("04-04-2020 09:00"), ("04/13/19 9:12"), ("04/14/19 2:13"), ("04/15/19 10:14"), ("04/16/19 5:15")).toDF("DOB")

    val tsformats = Seq("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm", "MM/dd/yy H:mm")

    DF.select(UtoTimestamp(tsformats)('DOB)).show
```

And here is the output -

```
+-------------------+
|           UDF(DOB)|
+-------------------+
|2020-02-04 08:02:00|
|2020-03-04 10:02:00|
|2020-04-04 09:00:00|
|2019-04-13 09:12:00|
|2019-04-14 02:13:00|
|2019-04-15 10:14:00|
|2019-04-16 05:15:00|
+-------------------+
```

Cherry on top would be to avoid having to write UtoTimestamp(colname) for many columns in your dataframe.
Let's write a function which accepts a Dataframe, List of all Timestamp columns, And all possible formats which your source data may have coded timestamps in..

It'd parse all timestamp columns for you with trying against formats..

```
def WithTimestampParsed(df: DataFrame, tsCols: Seq[String], tsformats: Seq[String]): DataFrame = {

    val colSelector = df.columns.map {
      c =>
        {
          if (tsCols.contains(c)) UtoTimestamp(tsformats)(col(c)) alias (c)
          else col(c)
        }
    }
```

Use it like this -

```
// You can pass as many column names in a sequence to be parsed
WithTimestampParsed(DF, Seq("DOB"), tsformats).show
```

Output -

```
+-------------------+
|                DOB|
+-------------------+
|2020-02-04 08:02:00|
|2020-03-04 10:02:00|
|2020-04-04 09:00:00|
|2019-04-13 09:12:00|
|2019-04-14 02:13:00|
|2019-04-15 10:14:00|
|2019-04-16 05:15:00|
+-------------------+
```

**EDIT** -
I saw latest spark code, and they are also using java.time._ utils now to parse dates and timestamps which enable handling beyond Milliseconds.. Earlier these functions were based on SimpleDateFormat ( I wasn't relying on to_timestamps of spark earlier due to this limit) .

So with to_date & to_timestamp functions being so reliable now.. Let's use them instead of having to write a UDF.. Let's write a function which operates on Columns.

```
def to_timestamp_simple(col: org.apache.spark.sql.Column, formats: Seq[String]): org.apache.spark.sql.Column = {
    coalesce(formats.map(fmt => to_timestamp(col, fmt)): _*)
  }
```

and with this WithTimestampParsedwould look like -

```
def WithTimestampParsedSimple(df: DataFrame, tsCols: Seq[String], tsformats: Seq[String]): DataFrame = {

    val colSelector = df.columns.map {
      c =>
        {
          if (tsCols.contains(c)) to_timestamp_simple(col(c), tsformats) alias (c)
          else col(c)
        }
    }

    df.select(colSelector: _*)
  }
```

And use it like -

```
DF.select(to_timestamp_simple('DOB,tsformats)).show

//OR

WithTimestampParsedSimple(DF, Seq("DOB"), tsformats).show
```

Output looks like -

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|coalesce(to_timestamp(`DOB`, 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm'), to_timestamp(`DOB`, 'MM/dd/yy H:mm'))|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                    2020-02-04 08:02:00|
|                                                                    2020-03-04 10:02:00|
|                                                                    2020-04-04 09:00:00|
|                                                                    2019-04-13 09:12:00|
|                                                                    2019-04-14 02:13:00|
|                                                                    2019-04-15 10:14:00|
|                                                                    2019-04-16 05:15:00|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

+-------------------+
|                DOB|
+-------------------+
|2020-02-04 08:02:00|
|2020-03-04 10:02:00|
|2020-04-04 09:00:00|
|2019-04-13 09:12:00|
|2019-04-14 02:13:00|
|2019-04-15 10:14:00|
|2019-04-16 05:15:00|
+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I put some code that maybe can help you in some way. 
I tried this

```
mport org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import java.sql.Date
import java.util.{GregorianCalendar}


object DateFormats {

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("Multiline")
    .master("local[*]")
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "4") //Change to a more reasonable default number of partitions for our data
    .config("spark.app.id", "Multiline")  // To silence Metrics warning
    .getOrCreate()

  val sc = spark.sparkContext

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)


    try {

      import spark.implicits._

      val DF = Seq(("02-04-2020 08:02"),("03-04-2020 10:02"),("04-04-2020 09:00"),("04/13/19 9:12"),("04/14/19 2:13"),("04/15/19 10:14"), ("04/16/19 5:15")).toDF("DOB")

      import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{to_date, to_timestamp}
      val DOBDF = DF.withColumn("Date", to_date($"DOB", "MM/dd/yyyy"))

      DOBDF.show()

      // todo: my code below
      DF
        .rdd
        .map(r =>{
            if(r.toString.contains("-")) {
              val dat = r.toString.substring(1,11).split("-")
              val calendar = new GregorianCalendar(dat(2).toInt,dat(1).toInt - 1,dat(0).toInt)
              (r.toString, new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis))
            } else {
              val dat = r.toString.substring(1,9).split("/")
              val calendar = new GregorianCalendar(dat(2).toInt + 2000,dat(0).toInt - 1,dat(1).toInt)
              (r.toString, new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis))
            }

        })
        .toDF("DOB","DATE")
        .show()

      // To have the opportunity to view the web console of Spark: http://localhost:4040/
      println("Type whatever to the console to exit......")
      scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
    } finally {
      sc.stop()
      println("SparkContext stopped.")
      spark.stop()
      println("SparkSession stopped.")
    }
  }
}
```

```
+------------------+----------+
|               DOB|      DATE|
+------------------+----------+
|[02-04-2020 08:02]|2020-04-02|
|[03-04-2020 10:02]|2020-04-03|
|[04-04-2020 09:00]|2020-04-04|
|   [04/13/19 9:12]|2019-04-13|
|   [04/14/19 2:13]|2019-04-14|
|  [04/15/19 10:14]|2019-04-15|
|   [04/16/19 5:15]|2019-04-16|
+------------------+----------+
```

Regards

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort and time, Accepted solution is more relevant to my problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `coalesce` function as mentioned in the **accepted answer**. On each format mismatch, `to_date` returns `null`, which makes coalesce to move to the next format in the list.

But with `to_date`, if you have issues in parsing the correct year component in the date in `yy` format (In the date `7-Apr-50`, if you want 50 to be parsed as 1950 or 2050), refer to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60629893/spark-date-format-issue)

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.coalesce

  // Reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html
  val parsedDateCol: Column = coalesce(
    // Four letters of M looks for full name of the Month
    to_date(col("original_date"), "MMMM, yyyy"),
    to_date(col("original_date"), "dd-MMM-yy"),
    to_date(col("original_date"), "yyyy-MM-dd"),
    to_date(col("original_date"), "d-MMM-yy")
  )

  // I have used some dummy dataframe name.
  dataframeWithDateCol.select(
      parsedDateCol.as("parsed_date")
    )
    .show()
```

Comment: trick using coalesce using spark function. already covered in accepted answer..

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing it out. I will take down my answer if you insist. I tried to cover only coalesce and an additional notes on handling year format. I thought it provides a value add in a different way, by just focussing purely on coalesce and not having any other way of doing it.