# Why pyspark converting string date values to null?

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-sql-database, databricks, azure-databricks

**Question**: Why the `myTimeStampCol1` in the following code is returning a null value in the third row, and how can we fix the issue?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df=spark.createDataFrame(data = [ ("1","Arpit","2021-07-24 12:01:19.000"),("2","Anand","2019-07-22 13:02:20.000"),("3","Mike","11-16-2021 18:00:08")],
schema=["id","Name","myTimeStampCol"])
df.select(col("myTimeStampCol"),to_timestamp(col("myTimeStampCol"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS").alias("myTimeStampCol1")).show()
```

**Output**

```
+--------------------+-------------------+
|myTimeStampCol      | myTimeStampCol1|
+--------------------+-------------------+
|2021-07-24 12:01:...|2021-07-24 12:01:19|
|2019-07-22 13:02:...|2019-07-22 13:02:20|
| 11-16-2021 18:00:08|               null|
```

**Remarks**:

1. I'm running the code in a python notebook in `Azure Databricks` (that is almost the same as `Databricks`)
2. Above example is just a sample to explain the issue. The real code is importing a data file with millions of records. And the file has a column that has the format `MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss` (for example `11-16-2021 18:00:08`) and all the values in that column have exact same format `MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss`

Comment: Hey @nam, where are you running this code?

Comment: @SaideepArikontham-MT I just added a **Remarks** section to my post

Comment: @SaideepArikontham-MT Per your suggestion, I edited the tags.

Comment: Does this column contain records with both `MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss` format and `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` format?

Comment: @SaideepArikontham-MT for other readers' benefit, just added additional content in Remark 2 of my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because of the difference in formats. Since all the records in this column are in the format `MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss`, You can modify the code as following.

```
df.select(col("myTimeStampCol"),to_timestamp(col("myTimeStampCol"),'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss').alias("myTimeStampCol1")).show(truncate=False)

#only if all the records in this column are 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss' format
```

- to_timestamp() column expects either 1 or 2 arguments, a column with these timestamp values and the second is the ***format of these values***. Since all these values are the same format `MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss`, you can specify this as the second argument.
- A sample output for this case is given in the below image:

[image]

Comment: Your suggestion worked for the cases where date column has exact same format for all its values (you also mentioned that). And hence, it works for my real example, as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seem like your timestamp pattern at index #3 is not aligned with others.
Spark uses the default patterns: `yyyy-MM-dd` for dates and `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` for timestamps.

Changing the format should solve the problem: `2021-11-16 18:00:08`

---

**Edit #1:**
Alternatively, creating custom transformation function may be a good idea. (Sorry I only found the example with scala).
[Spark : Parse a Date / Timestamps with different Formats (MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm, MM/dd/yy H:mm ) in same column of a Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60986710/spark-parse-a-date-timestamps-with-different-formats-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmm-mm-d)

Comment: I just added **Remarks** section to my post. The read data file has millions of records, and changing the date format is not an option.

Comment: @nam As far as I know, I believe that it is impossible to handle different patterns with build-in function on a single operation. May be you could try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60986710/spark-parse-a-date-timestamps-with-different-formats-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmm-mm-d

Comment: In my case, in the real data file, the date column has exact same format for all records. I have explained a bit more in remarks 2 of my post.